# Display in Terminal the Python code running

Tags: python, macos, terminal

sorry if it's stupid, not clear or not even the good place to ask...

in order to get sys.argv from a file (drag and dropping it), i've made an automator app .
here is the code fromthe script.py :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import os

file=sys.argv[1:][0]
print(file)

try:
    os.makedirs(('/'.join(file.split('/')[:-1]))+"/new")
except:
    OSError
    pass
```

so basicaly i drag and drop a file on my"app" ,in the file directory,the scripts makes a new folder. 
but i can't see myprintoutput anywhere

How could I have a console showing me what happens ( in windows, i use a DAT file that runs the script, but everything is traced in the CMD )

thanks a lot
guillaume

Comment: If you're not running the script from a terminal window, where do you expect the output to show?

Comment: BTW, `sys.argv[1:][0]` is the same as just `sys.argv[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Hum I am not sure I understand the question ....

so I might not bring the right answer.

1) run your code from the Powershell  ( make  sure your python is properly link...)

2) add under  "os.makedirs...."    (for python 3) : 
print (  '/'.join(file.split('/')[:-1]))+"/new" )

3) save  and run

if it solves the  your problem ,  consider it as answer, I need points ..... :)

Comment: The question is about how to see the output if you use drag-and-drop to drop a file on the script.

Comment: He just wants to see the output of `print(file)`